# How do I turn a Web Scraping code into a Loop?

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping

I was able to loop the web scraping process, but the data collected from the page that comes after replaces the data from the page before. Making the excel contains only the data from the last page. What do I need to do?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
print ('all imported successfuly')


for x in range(1, 44):
    link = (f'https://www.trustpilot.com/review/birchbox.com?page={x}')
    print (link)
    req = requests.get(link)
    content = req.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")
    names = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'consumer-information__name'})
    headers = soup.find_all('h2', attrs={'class':'review-content__title'})
    bodies = soup.find_all('p', attrs={'class':'review-content__text'})
    ratings = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'star-rating star-rating--medium'})
    dates = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'review-content-header__dates'})


print ('pass1')

df = pd.DataFrame({'User Name': names, 'Header': headers, 'Body': bodies, 'Rating': ratings, 'Date': dates})
df.to_csv('birchbox006.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
print ('excel done')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know number of pages, you can put your scraping in loop like:

```
for i in range(1,44):
    req = requests.get("https://www.trustpilot.com/review/birchbox.com?page={}".format(i)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to run this once and you know the total number of pages, all you have to do is change the url you are calling accordingly and then concatenate the resulting dataframes.

One way of doing it (assuming you have python 3.6 or newer for f-strings) is:

```
df = None
for i in range(1, 44):
    req = requests.get(f"https://www.trustpilot.com/review/birchbox.com?page={i}")
    content = req.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")
    names = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'consumer-information__name'})
    headers = soup.find_all('h2', attrs={'class':'review-content__title'})
    bodies = soup.find_all('p', attrs={'class':'review-content__text'})
    ratings = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'star-rating star-rating--medium'})
    dates = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'review-content-header__dates'})

    print ('pass1')


    if df is None:
        df = pd.DataFrame({'User Name':names,'Header':headers,'Body':bodies,'Rating':ratings,'Date':dates})
    else:
        df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame({'User Name':names,'Header':headers,'Body':bodies,'Rating':ratings,'Date':dates})])
```

if you are using an older version of python, you can replace that line with `req = requests.get("https://www.trustpilot.com/review/birchbox.com?page={}".format(i))`